# broadcasting laravel event and multiple channels

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io

I am new in laravel so I googled a lot for different approaches how to create websocket with redis, socket.io in laravel framework.
And finally my websocket works as I expected. However I still have unanswered questions related with websockets.
Could you please help me find answer?

`class TestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast` this class definition expects broadcastOn method that broadcasting channel or channels with data to the listeners. Listener in my case is server.js

```
redis.subscribe('test-channel', 'test-channel-new');
redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {..
```

as you can see, I want to subscribe two channels, but with different return values for each channel. And I have no luck find any explanation how it achieved. Have I create new event for each channel separately or there exist some trick using broadcastWith?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's very easy! just return arrays of Channels in broadcastOn method 
I just did this: 
Example:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return [
        new PrivateChannel('App.Message.' . $this->message->to_user_id),
        new PrivateChannel('App.Message.'. $this->message->to_user_id .'.From.'. $this->message->from_user_id)
    ];
}
```